# Spring integration tutorials, information,examples?

Tags: enterprise, spring-integration, eai

I am new to spring Integration. I read that it is flexible and light weight integration technology build on Spring framework. It is used for Enterprise Application Integration (EAI).

Where can I find good tutorials and examples of spring Integrations?

I already have some pdf from Spring community site,However those all are more theoreticle.
Please help me finding any simple and easy to understand documents and tutorials.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I know that. Only intention to ask this question here is, there are lots of links available on google and I am confused about which one to read. It is always better to ask some experienced person,who knows which documents are better.I am sorry to ask such generic question.

Comment: @Sagar: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034054/when-to-use-spring-integration-vs-camel) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191693/feasibility-of-spring-integration) (follow blogs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to visit the Spring Integration homepage: http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration

If you have questions after exploring the resources there, then you can ask those questions in our forum:
http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?f=42

Hope that helps.
-Mark Fisher (Spring Integration lead)