# Feasibility of Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration .There a few questions I have regarding spring integration

- What are some real time scenarios in
  which spring integration can be
  implemented ?
- What is the advantage of creating an
  extra spring integratio layer ?
- If a mailing system is not
  implemented in spring , can spring
  integration still be used for
  integration ?

Is it something like spring integration can connect two systems developed in two different languages?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention Enterprise Integration Patterns described here - http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/

Answer (score 2):

And, also, you might check out https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/24/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-integration which introduces Spring Integration as well as the basic paradigms. It'll get you started and then you can start to make sense of the samples and so on.

Answer (score 2):

**What are some real time scenarios in which spring integration can be implemented ?**

> I would say its best for building an
>   application using the pipes and
>   filters architecture, primarily for
>   **intra-application architecture and
>   design**. By intra-application, i mean
>   'within an application'. It is suited
>   for intra-application because of the
>   light-weight pipes(channels) based on
>   the util.concurrent classes. For
>   example the DirectChannel is a simple
>   and logical way to separate two
>   processing nodes in a workflow without
>   an overhead of a queue (not the jms
>   queue).
>
> It does support interaction between
>   applications through gateways that
>   adapt to various messaging mechanisms
>   (like WebServices, JMS etc). So the
>   application doesn't have to turn to
>   some other framework for
>   inter-application interaction either.

**What is the advantage of creating an extra spring integratio layer ?**

> Its useful if you want **separation of
>   concerns, loose coupling and
>   flexibility**.

**If a mailing system is not implemented in spring , can spring integration still be used for integration ?**

> I don't understand the question, sorry.

**Is it something like spring integration can connect two systems developed in two different languages?**

> You mean, interact with another system that's based on a non-java platform? That can be achieved too, but not primarily because of Spring Integration but by using Spring Integration with existing mechanisms for exchanging messages like WebServices, JMS etc. *If the requirement is just a point-to-point messaging between 2 applications, Spring Integration is not going to be of much use (unless there is an interesting workflow of sorts in such a dialogue).*

Answer (score 1):

The real scenarios are to many to mention. Spring Integration is a framework that allows you to architect message-driven systems based on Enterprise Integration Patterns.
Note, when I say Messaging I am not implying remote messaging such as JMS or anything like that. Messaging first and foremost is an is an architectural paradigm (pattern) which allows you to build loosely coupled and scalable systems such as the one described here: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/03/18/eip-loan-broker-reference-implementation-part-1/
Spring Integration also provides remote adapters (TCP, HTTP, MAIL etc.) to integrate with remote systems. We have many samples that you can go through to get more details http://blog.springsource.com/2010/09/29/new-spring-integration-samples/

I think by going through the articles you'll get the sense of "what is the advantage". ALl I want to state now is that IMO the advantage is the framework itself. By using it you'll spare yourself from writing integration code.

"If a mailing system is not implemented in spring , can spring integration still be used for integration ?" - I am not sure I understand the question. Spring Integration is using JavaMail API to communicate with emails servers (both send and receive). Could you please elaborate?