# Practical use cases of Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have started learning spring integration. As of now  learnt that it provides features like transformers, filters etc 
But I am not getting what can be practical use cases of spring integration. Say if I have to just transform java object to xml/json or vice versa.
Should I go ahead with spring integration . I think no as it can be achieved with their 3rd part libraries also . So what can be the use cases of
spring integration ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Feasibility of Spring Integration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191693/feasibility-of-spring-integration)

Comment: I don't want to copy/paste the docs and blogs here, but just send you to the Enterprise Integration theory: http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very much used for enterprise integration.There are many theories and examples that you may have read. I can give you one scenario where we are currently using Spring integration.
We manage a business system in which we have to connect to different telecom operator with different kind service to get some information.Now some telecom operator uses email,soap based web service ,restfull webservice,Sockets ,ftp etc and all these we need to integrate our system. So we have one component which integrates with all the operator just by some simple configuration and very minimal codes.

Comment: you mean to say that you are using routing service of SI where if telecom operator uses email, you will call email service, and if telecom operator uses soap based web service  you will call that specific service. Is that right ?

Comment: @emilly not only that we receive the data accordingly,transform ,parse ,perform some business logic and do manipulation according to the operator.Some of the code and configuration are shared between operators.We were able to achieve great deal of loose coupling.

Comment: @SarfarazKhan, in your case, Is it possible to use Spring Batch instead Spring Integration ? Which one will be better in in this case ?