# Spring Integration versus Camel

Tags: apache-camel, spring-integration

We are using Spring Integration to read from a database, transform into XML, and then place messages onto a topic for an external system. Would there be any reasons to favour Camel for this use case? Also, in general, what advantages, if any, does Camel have over Spring Integration?

A related question: for development using Spring projects such as Batch, Data and XD, how seamless would it be to use Camel with these technologies, in comparison to Spring Integration.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034054/when-to-use-spring-integration-vs-camel

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few links that discuss Spring Integration vs Camel.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/light-weight-open-source
http://www.javacodebook.com/2013/07/24/spring-integration-vs-apache-camel/
[When to use Spring Integration vs. Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034054/when-to-use-spring-integration-vs-camel)

Note that Camel uses Spring for configuration and can easily integrate with other Spring projects such as Batch, http://camel.apache.org/springbatch.html, XD and others.

Nothing requires you to go with a pure Spring stack though many choose to do so. I find Camel a much more pleasant choice than SI in my day to day work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to start one more holly war regarding Spring Integration vs Apache Camel, but I'd say: it's up to you, which one to choose for development.

As you noticed Batch, Data and XD, and, of course, Integration, all are projects of Spring.
And what is interest XD is written on Spring Integration and the last one is main tool to extend the XD Runtime.

So, I won't mind that you can write some adapter for Camel in the XD, but will it make sense, if you can just concentrate on your business task with existing abilities from XD via Integration and Spring at all?..

Anyway Spring Integration is a part of Spring IO platform. And you should agree with me, that one Camel can't replace entire platform.

Comment: it's really good opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can find some links to what other people have blogged/written about Apache Camel vs competitors at

- http://camel.apache.org/articles