# In Spring boot application which Integration tool (Apache camel or Spring integration) easy or better for IBM MQ

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, spring-integration, ibm-mq

We are using spring boot application with IBM MQ, so Which integration tool is better Apache camel or Spring integration

*as I'm new for these technologies and it's higher priority decision so I'm making it a separate question, if it exists so could you please comment link then I will refer it.*

Comment: How fast do you wanted to be?

Comment: which one will give a fast and better performance that one I want to use

Comment: I hope you understand that was sarcasm specifically to point out the fundamental flaw in your overall question. What is fast? What is better? What is performant? You did not specify your expected SLA requirement; you did not specify your business requirement you did not provide any details at all. You simply threw words like performance, features, memory and threads and stated that you want all that to be shinier then the other which is absolutely impossible to answer in any objective way. Don't take it the wrong way. .  just trying to help

Comment: thanks @OlegZhurakousky for reply

Comment: I have edited the question please refer once and give me your suggestions

Comment: Better in what way?  What are your requirements?  I just did a google search for "Which is better Apache camel or Spring integration" and one of the first results was a SO post [When to use Spring Integration vs. Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034054/when-to-use-spring-integration-vs-camel), maybe this will be helpful to you.

Comment: I mean which integration tool  easy way to working with spring boot and IBM MQ

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that Apache Camel uses Spring JMS for the messaging component. So your are looking to use Spring JMS regardless of the other technologies. If you are looking at Camel and Spring Boot, have a look at [Spring Boot - Camel - IBM MQ](https://github.com/grovedc/CamelSpringJMS/tree/testing/bridge).  This example makes good use of connection pooling.

The example also uses JTA synchronized transactions for reliable message delivery (DUPS_OK mode, not XA).  This can be difficult to achieve.